Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Canary 5 has sync errors after downloading
I downloaded the latest Android Studio Koala (2024.1.1 Canary 5) and AS said that this version only works with Android gradle plugin 8.5.0-alpha05. So I updated the AGP and then got the following error:

Querying the mapped value of flatmap(provider(task 'processDebugGoogleServices', class com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask)) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

I think it's related to Google Services, but I am using the latest version for Google Services.
Canary 4 was working perfectly so I am not sure what the problem is.
this is the version catalog
[versions]
agp = "8.5.0-alpha05"
koinVersion = "3.5.3"
kspKoinVersion = "1.3.1"
kotlin = "1.9.23"
coreKtx = "1.12.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.7.0"
activityCompose = "1.8.2"
composeBom = "2024.04.00"
conventionalCommitsVersion = "3.1.3"
ktorVersion = "2.3.3"
logbackClassicVersion = "1.2.3"
appcompat = "1.6.1"
material = "1.11.0"
kotlinxSerializationJsonVersion = "1.6.0"
materialIconsExtended = "1.6.5"
serializationVersion = "1.9.0"
jetbrainsKotlinJvm = "1.9.21"
ktfmtVersion = "0.17.0"
coroutinesTest = "1.8.0"
securityCryptoVersion = "1.0.0"
timberVersion = "5.0.1"
lifecycleRuntimeComposeVersion = "2.7.0"
googleServices = "4.4.1"
firebaseAuth = "22.3.1"
material3Android = "1.2.1"
uiTooling = "1.6.4"
voyager = "1.0.0"
kspVersion = "1.9.23-1.0.20"

googleServices = { id = "com.google.gms.google-services", version.ref = "googleServices" }

The bounty attracted a ChatGPT (or similar) plagiariser.

I google services is not ready for that version of agp.
However, downgrading to this version everything seems to work ok
agp = "8.3.2"

